# How to add a clearfix div after every 4 hits with Algolia?

Tags: javascript, search, laravel-5, algolia

We're trying to implement instant search with Algolia. It works like a charm. The only thing is we would like to add a clearfix div after every 4 hits. Right now it's

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="ais-hits">

    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>

</div>
```

I would like to have a clearfix div afer every 4 results like so:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="ais-hits">

    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="ais-hits--item"></div>

</div>
```

This is the code to generate the hits widget

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#booksearch',
        templates: {
            item: getTemplate('result')
        },
        cssClasses: {
            item: 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3'
        },
        hitsPerPage: 12
    })
);

search.start();
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstantSearch widgets do not provide that feature.

However, you can write your own JS script which adds the `div` after the rendering (i.e. generation) of the HTML code. To do so, simply wait the `render` event to be triggered. More details about that in the [**Events** section of the InstantSearch documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#events).

Comment: Thank you so much!. I added some jquery that checked on every render, the 4th element, and i then added the clearfix div